# How do we determine what is the temperature (or beta or energy) of a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, hamiltonian, density-operator

In statistical physics, we learn about the "inverse temperature of the system" as $\beta = \frac{1}{k_B T}$. Now in most cases we'd leave $\beta$ as a free parameter, and then calculate the (say) the partition function depending upon $\beta$.

I want to know, given a density matrix $\rho$ of a system that's not necessarily pure and follows the dynamics according to $\mathcal{H}$, is it possible to determine a corresponding $\beta$, since we know all the eigenstates of the system and hence its energy?

Edit: The system does not necessarily obey the thermalisation hypothesis!

Comment: If the density matrix doesn’t have Boltzmann distribution, are you asking “what would be the temperature if the system were to come into thermal equilibrium?”

Comment: @Dave I'm aware that there won't be a concept of temperature if the system doesn't thermalize. So yes, I'm asking for the temperature of the system if it were to thermalize. Shouldn't we then be able to find the energy of the system and use $E = k_B T$ to find beta?

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to confirm the meaning of the question with the edit.  Maybe another way of phrasing it might be "given an arbitrary density matrix, what would the equilibrium temperature be if the system came to equilibrium without exchanging any (heat) energy with the environment?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but if the system is in thermal equilibrium then $\rho = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta H}$. If you know all the eigenvalues $E_i$, then in the energy eigenbasis this becomes $p_i = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta E_i}$. The factor of $Z$ is annoying because it has a complicated nonlinear dependence on $\beta$, but fortunately you can get rid of it by considering the ratio of two probabilities:
$$\frac{p_i}{p_j} = \frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{e^{-\beta E_j}} = e^{-\beta (E_i - E_j)} \implies \beta = \frac{\ln \left( \frac{p_i}{p_j} \right)}{E_j - E_i}.$$

Comment: This looks good. We have access to all the eigenvalues and bases of the system (through the Hamiltonian, of course) so in theory we should be able to carry out this calculation, right?

Comment: @pyroscepter Yes, and in fact you don't even need the entire spectrum, you just need two (unequal) probabilities and the corresponding state energies

Comment: thanks! Easy enough calculation that I didn't spot on my own. Accepted your answer.